# How is the Mobius function multiplicative?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

My course notes define the Mobius function,

> For an integer $n>0$ we set $$\mu(n)=\begin{cases}1&n=1, \\ 0& p^2|n \text{ for some } p, \\ (-1)^r & n=p_1\dots p_r,\; p_i\text{ distinct primes}\end{cases}$$

and assert that $\mu$ is multiplicative.

But suppose $n=p_1\dots p_{r_n},\;m=q_1\dots q_{r_m}$ with $\text{gcd}(n,m)>1$, e.g. $n=m=2$. Then $$\mu(n)\mu(m)=(-1)^{r_n}\times(-1)^{r_m}=\pm1\neq0=\mu(nm).$$ What's gone wrong?

Comment: Nothing. Being multiplicative means that $\gcd(m,n)=1\implies\mu(mn)=\mu(m)\mu(n)$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos That'll be it. Thanks.

Comment: That's the difference between [Completely multiplicative function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_multiplicative_function) and [multiplicative function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function)